# Accessing innerText inside Component

Tags: html, angular, markdown

I'm having pretty simple component that looks like this and basicly does the job.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-code',
  template: ' <pre><code [highlight]="code" [languages]="languages" [lineNumbers]="true"></code></pre> '
})
export class CodeComponent {

  readonly languages = ['java'];

  @Input()
  code = '';

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

But, I'd like to make minor change to it

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-code',
  template: '<pre><code [highlight]="code" [languages]="languages" [lineNumbers]="true"></code></pre>'
})
export class CodeComponent {

  readonly languages = ['java'];

  code = '';

  constructor(private elem: ElementRef) {
     this.code = elem.nativeElement.innerText;
  }
}
```

So instead of writing 
`<app-code [code]="'some code goes here'"></app-code>` 
I can write 
`<app-code>some code goes here</app-code>`

Unfortunatelly, It's not working, my code block remains empty

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get `innerText` because `CodeComponent` is not drawn.

You need to use `ngAfterViewInit`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-code',
  template: '<pre><code [highlight]="code" [languages]="languages" [lineNumbers]="true"></code></pre>'
})
export class CodeComponent {

  readonly languages = ['java'];

  code = '';

  constructor(private elem: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.code = elem.nativeElement.innerText;
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it isn't working, value of my `code` is still an empty string.